# user mailer showing special character

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

as we all know that html_safe work in controller and view 
i am sending some data from user_mailer.rb file and its having some special character like if i wrote &"samarth" so its show &amd&quotsamarth&quot 
the code is

def alert_publication_notification(user, cust_alert, home_url)

```
load_mailer_settings
@content_type = "text/html"
@subject = ("[abc]- #{cust_alert.alert.name.html_safe} : mail ") due to this line i am getting special character any solution 
@from = "sam"
@recipients = user.login
@bcc = Settings.emailid_alerts
@sent_on = Time.now
@customer_alert = cust_alert
@user = user
@home_url = home_url
```

end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `raw(some_variable)` function for RAILS 3 this will not show encoded characters.

Comment: how can we use raw in user mailer

Comment: checkout this guide. this might help you:
http://techspry.com/ruby_and_rails/html_safe-and-helpers-in-rails-3-mystery-solved/

Comment: Raw method is not working in user mailer which is in app/mailer folder